# Read d3 keys values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have `csv file` whose headers are `Station ID`, `Elev`, `Latitude`, `Longitude`,  `County`,   `Nat_ID`,   `Year_Built`,   `Capacity`, `YrsStr1`, `YrsStr2`, .....
Here i want to get values of all columns from `YrsStr1` till `YrsSt578` and skipping other column values. Below is the code for skipping the columns but I am unable to get column values?

```
 var hd = d3.keys(res[0]);

        for (var i = hd.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            if( (hd[i] === "Station") || (hd[i] === "ID") || (hd[i] === "Elev") || (hd[i] === "Latitude")
                || (hd[i] === "Longitude") || (hd[i] === "County") || (hd[i] === "Nat_ID") || (hd[i] === "Year_Built")
                || (hd[i] === "Capacity")){
            }else{

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use
           if(hd[i].includes("YrsStr")){

codepen URL for reference
http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/pbyvmG

```
               for (var i = hd.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                   if(hd[i].includes("YrsStr")){
                        console.log("key"+hd[i] +"--value"+res[hd[i]]);
                }
```

Comment: For testing..i have used sample data and gave alert to check the value...Hope this is helpful for you